# Pronunciation of "gender"?

Tags: pronunciation

Recently I heard native speakers pronouncing 'gender' with a soft 'g', almost sounding like 'jan' from 'January'. I've instantly looked it up at dict.cc and YouTube: seems like this is the correct pronunciation.

However, I'm wondering why the 'g' isn't a hard 'g'. I mean 'get' or 'git' (the software), 'goal' and many more have a hard 'g', thus not sounding like a 'j' at all.

Is there any rule of thumb for the pronunciation of a 'g'? How can I ascertain whether a word should be pronounced with a soft or hard 'g'?

Comment: You might ask this question at our sister site [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204231/should-g-followed-by-e-and-i-be-pronounced-with-a-soft-or-hard-g) -  it is on-topic there. Visit this [link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/pronunciation/english/gender) to hear the word as it is always pronounced, with a soft **g** as in _/dʒ/iraffe_ or a/dʒ/enda._

Comment: @P.E.Dant: It's on topic here too, in that any rules of thumb that exist would be quite handy for learners. (Assuming there *are* any: I am dubious.)

Comment: Then how do you decide if its a soft or hard 'g'? Aren't there any rules? Is it random?

Comment: Of course it's not random, in English or any language. No language has genuine _rules._ If they did, it would be very easy to learn them. Read the link at ELU and search there for more posts on the subject.

Comment: @NathanTuggy A subset of pronunciation questions may be on topic, but when we start talking about the /g/ sound and Germanic roots, aren't we well over the line into etymology and language history?

Comment: @P.E.Dant: If learners need to know about roots to understand a helpful rule for them, I don't see why we can't give them something of that, although it's likely to be a different treatment than ELU would give.

Comment: I agree with you @NathanTuggy and I certainly don't ever want to turn anyone away. I'm dubious about supporting a belief in rules, even of thumb, though. Where pronunciation is concerned, there are so many exceptions to every one of them that I think the question might reveal a better answer at ELU. I haven't totalled them, but my guess is that there are more exceptions than rules!

Comment: Related: [How to identify the correct pronunciation for letter “g” before “i” or “e”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18831)

Comment: @sumelic The answer at that link is confused. /ʒ/ is _not_ the soft "g." This will just cause more confusion, I think. The best link is probsbly the [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_and_soft_G).

Comment: How is a new student of English supposed to know whether a given word has a Latin or Germanic root? I suspect this is one of the reasons for the proscription, however gentle, of questions of pronunciation and etymology in the Help center.

Comment: Being a non-native speaker, I have to resort to dictionaries a lot of times. (How am I supposed to know the pronunciations of words like *gigabyte*, *gargantuan*, *gigantic*, *gaol*, or *phlegm* the first time I run into them?! It's not only *g*. It's everywhere. Even simple words like *awry*, *niche*, or *colonel* are not quite intuitive. Not to mention fancier words and names like *brougham*, or *Aslackby and Laughton*!) If someone asked me if there's any rule of thumb for the pronunciation of 'g', I might tell them, "Dictionaries"! :-)

Comment: @DamkerngT Also: *gnat*, *gnu*, *gymnasium*, *gynecology*, *Geoff*, *give*, *gibe*, etc (perhaps my all time favorite: *victuals*)

Comment: They don't begin with _g,_ but I would like to take this opportunity to apologize to you, and every student of English, for _though, enough, plough and through,_ @DamkerngT

Answer (score 2):

English has words derived from many languages, some with different orthographies.

> gender

derives from Latin and Old French, and words from that lineage use the soft g before  **e**

> get

derives from Norse, which uses the hard g before "e"

So as a rule of thumb, if the vowel following the g is a non-front vowel (a, o u) then the g is hard. Otherwise (e, i, y) you need to know whether the word is Latinate (soft g) or Germanic(hard g).

No doubt there will be many exceptions to this rule, not least of which is Margarine, which is pronounced with a soft g, unlike Margaret with a hard g.

You may find [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_vowel) [articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_and_soft_G) interesting.